# Why bulk of HPGe detectors is doped?

Tags: nuclear-physics, semiconductor-physics, radiation, gamma-rays, instrument

When I am looking at schematic diagrams of HPGe gamma spectrometer detectors (like this Ortec GLP one), it is often mentioned that bulk of Ge is doped. In this example - P-type doped. Is there a reason why doped germanium is used rather than truly pure (undoped, "High Purity") one? Or resistance of undoped germanium is too high at cryogenic temperatures?

[image: HPGe]

Comment: isn't the detector meant to be a p-n junction structure? not quite sure with your question but as I understand it, we want to have a p-n junction in our detectors/sensors. If your question is why we want to have a p-n junction structure, that is depend on the applications, but remember, bipolar devices have higher current capability. I checked in the data sheet of that detector, no info about temperature. Maybe you can check the mobility in Ge at your temperature of interest.
edit grammar

Comment: in general, we dope the semiconductor because we want to have a certain value of charge carrier which is not sensitive to temperature. this way we can control the electrical properties of the device, e.g., conductivity.